# How to hide dashes on right sidebar in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to get rid off these dashes on right scrollbar of the editor

[image]

It's like minimap to indicate the current highlightings in editor.

Update:
I think this feature is [Bar mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2017#bar-mode) But still I don't know how to change it.

I'm using VS Code for OSX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove symbols on right scrollbar of vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002585/how-can-i-remove-symbols-on-right-scrollbar-of-vscode)

Answer (score 3):

Go to Code > Preferences > Settings to open user settings and add following line `"editor.selectionHighlight": false,` and it will stop highlighting selection.

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out, [VS scroll bar has 2 modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2017#bar-mode): *Bar mode* and *Map mode*.

**To turn off annotations (in *Bar mode*):**

In VS, go to: *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars*

Uncheck: *Show annotations over vertical scroll bar*

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using VS Code for Mac

Comment: This answer doe not apply to VS code and is valid for visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the colors used in the overview ruler in your VS Code settings.json file. Use a transparent color such as `"#fff0"` to hide the annotations. The list of annotations is in [the VS Code docs here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors) (search for overview ruler).

For example, to turn off selection highlighting, bracket matching, and modifications in the scrollbar, add this to your settings.json file:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightForeground": "#fff0",
  "editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#fff0",
  "editorOverviewRuler.addedForeground": "#fff0",
  "editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground": "#fff0",
  "editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground": "#fff0",
},
```