# How can I remove symbols on right scrollbar of vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I remove the symbols on the right scrollbar in VSCode?
[image: Scrollbar symbols]

Comment: they seem related to code folding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to the **Overview ruler** in VSCode. This is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684408/472768). Copied below:

You can configure these settings:

```
// Controls if the cursor should be hidden in the overview ruler.
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": false,

// Controls if a border should be drawn around the overview ruler.
"editor.overviewRulerBorder": true,

// Controls the number of decorations that can show up at the same position in the overview ruler
"editor.overviewRulerLanes": 3
```

… but also some [configurable colours](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors), which is the most thorough explanation I've found:

> ### Overview ruler
>
> This ruler is located beneath the scroll bar on the right edge of the
>   editor and gives an overview of the decorations in the editor.
>
> - `editorOverviewRuler.border`: Color of the overview ruler border.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.findMatchForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **find matches**. The color must not be opaque to not hide
>     underlying decorations.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.rangeHighlightForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **highlighted ranges**, like by the Quick Open, Symbol in
>     File and Find features. The color must not be opaque to not hide
>     underlying decorations.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.selectionHighlightForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **selection highlights**. The color must not be opaque to
>     not hide underlying decorations.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **symbol highlights**. The color must not be opaque to not hide
>     underlying decorations.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightStrongForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **write-access symbol highlights**. The color must not be
>     opaque to not hide underlying decorations.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **modified content**.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.addedForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **added content**.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **deleted content**.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **errors**.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.warningForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **warnings**.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.infoForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **infos**.
> - `editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground`: Overview ruler marker color for **matching brackets**.

Comment: I haven't succeeded in disabling the overview ruler.
Can anyone on recent vscode builds share their config to disable it?

Comment: Changing the colours of every `editorOverviewRuler` attribute seems to work, after restarting vscode.
Otherwise, disabling the right scrollbar is kind of a killer: `"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 0`

Comment: `editor.overviewRulerBorder` is a life saver if your theme makes it hard to distinguish the border of the overview ruler with the line-length rulers (`editor.rulers`).

Answer (score 5):

As per [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85418#issuecomment-1040876221), a more recent solution would be to use use `workbench.colorCustomizations` to make the colors transparent:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        // OverviewRuler
        "editorOverviewRuler.border": "#0000",
        /// Search command
        "editorOverviewRuler.findMatchForeground": "#fff4",
        "editorOverviewRuler.rangeHighlightForeground": "#0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.selectionHighlightForeground": "#0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightForeground": "#0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightStrongForeground": "#0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground": "#0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.addedForeground": "#0000",
        "editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground": "#0000",
        //"editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground": "#0000ff",
        //"editorOverviewRuler.warningForeground": "#ff00ff",
        //"editorOverviewRuler.infoForeground": "#00ff00",
        "editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#0000",
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) to just make those overview ruler decorations transparent:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorOverviewRuler.addedForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.infoForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.warningForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.commentForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.commentUnresolvedForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.currentContentForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.commonContentForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.incomingContentForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.findMatchForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.rangeHighlightForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.selectionHighlightForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightStrongForeground": "#0000",
    "editorOverviewRuler.wordHighlightTextForeground": "#0000",
},
```

Descriptions for the above colour configuraiton points can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_editor-colors) or also just in the tooltips by hovering the mouse over them.

Also probably useful to look at:

```json
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": true,
"debug.showBreakpointsInOverviewRuler": false // should already be the default
```

There's also the `scm.diffDecorations`, but you may as well just use the above approach to make them transparent in the overview ruler.

---

If the above doesn't cover what you see, either it's a new builtin decoration and this answer needs updating, or it's a decoration coming from an extension (You can find out by disabling extensions or doing an extension bisect), in which case you should check the extension's settings or see if it contributes colour customization points for it.

Ex. The Todo Highlight extension has a `todohighlight.defaultStyle` setting with an `overviewRulerColor` property.