# How can I show scope in a VSCode scrollbar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, scope

In VSCode, is there a way to show the current scope or closure in the scrollbar, e.g. by a decoration or opacity change?

I'm looking for a way to see whether my `find widget` matches fall within the current scope, which is often larger than screen height.

As far as I can tell, there's nothing in `settings.json` for this, but perhaps I'm searching for the wrong terms.

I'd be open to an extension, but again, unless I'm searching for the wrong thing, this doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not a question that belongs on stack overflow, but I would still like an answer to this question – there are tons of extensions that do this though.

Comment: VSCode settings seem to be grey area -- there are tons of "how do I configure VSCode to do X" here.

Comment: Yeah. I mean a lot of the questions are pretty stupid, but this question actually contributes to the site

Answer (score 1):

In the scrollbar? No (not that I know of).

But at the top under the tabs it does show this information for me, but perhaps not in the way you are hoping for

[image]

---

### Edit

Using VSCode today I thought about this and noticed that matching braces on a function will highlight in the scrollbar when clicked, as well as any search result matches.  This might do what you want with no tweaks at all.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes, I do use that, but I'm looking for a way to see whether my find-widget matches fall within the current scope, which is often larger than screen height.

Comment: @ultraGentle see my edit. I noticed this today while working on something.

Comment: That would do it, yes -- but it doesn't happen on my installation.  I searched settings for `brackets` `braces` `scope` -- any chance you know what setting has enabled this?

Comment: Check out all settings related to `minimap` I think that might be what you're after

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to do the opposite
of [How can I remove symbols on right scrollbar of vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002585/how-can-i-remove-symbols-on-right-scrollbar-of-vscode) :

- `settings.json`
- `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {`
- `"editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground"` (Overview ruler marker color for matching brackets)

Unfortunately, this only happens when the cursor is touching an opening/closing bracket, not when the cursor is in the interior somewhere.